# I can't access the pod which scheduled to the another node. But i can access the pod which scheduled to the current node

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I can't  access the pod which scheduled to the another node. But i can access the pod which scheduled to the current node,  vice versa, when I on the another node, I only can access the pod which scheduled on current node, And can't access the pod which scheduled to another node. And the route rules on the current node is different from other node(In fact, all three nodes in my cluster have different route rules). some info are list below:

on the master node 172.16.5.150:

```
[root@localhost test-deploy]# kubectl get node
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
172.16.5.150   Ready    <none>   9h    v1.16.2
172.16.5.151   Ready    <none>   9h    v1.16.2
172.16.5.152   Ready    <none>   9h    v1.16.2
[root@localhost test-deploy]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       nginx-controller-5qvwn                     1/1     Running   0          46m
default       nginx-controller-kgjwm                     1/1     Running   0          46m
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-6dbf77c57f-kcqtt   1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   calico-node-5zdt7                          1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   calico-node-8vqhv                          1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   calico-node-w9tq8                          1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   coredns-7b6b59774c-lzfh7                   1/1     Running   0          9h
[root@localhost test-deploy]#
[root@localhost test-deploy]# kcp -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-controller-5qvwn   1/1     Running   0          23m   192.168.102.135   172.16.5.151   <none>           <none>
nginx-controller-kgjwm   1/1     Running   0          23m   192.168.102.134   172.16.5.150   <none>           <none>
[root@localhost test-deploy]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens32
172.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     100    0        0 ens32
192.168.102.128 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
192.168.102.129 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 calia42aeb87aa8
192.168.102.134 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 caliefbc513267b
[root@localhost test-deploy]# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.10.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    9h
nginx-svc    ClusterIP   10.10.189.192   <none>        8088/TCP   23m
[root@localhost test-deploy]# curl 192.168.102.135
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.102.135: 无效的参数
[root@localhost test-deploy]# curl 192.168.102.134
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
[root@localhost test-deploy]# curl 10.10.189.192:8088
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.10.189.192:8088; 没有到主机的路由
[root@localhost test-deploy]# curl 10.10.189.192:8088
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
[root@localhost test-deploy]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:4b:76:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.5.150/8 brd 172.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute ens32
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::92f8:9957:1651:f41/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:00:37:16:be:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: kube-ipvs0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether b2:9f:49:ff:31:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.1/32 brd 10.10.0.1 scope global kube-ipvs0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.0.200/32 brd 10.10.0.200 scope global kube-ipvs0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.189.192/32 brd 10.10.189.192 scope global kube-ipvs0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 192.168.102.128/32 brd 192.168.102.128 scope global tunl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: calia42aeb87aa8@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: caliefbc513267b@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On the another node 172.16.5.150:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl 10.10.189.192:8088
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.10.189.192:8088; 没有到主机的路由
[root@localhost ~]# curl 10.10.189.192:8088
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
[root@localhost ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
172.16.5.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
192.168.102.128 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
192.168.102.135 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali44ab0f7df0f
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:38:a2:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.5.151/24 brd 172.16.5.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e24a:6e5c:3a44:a7ee/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:91:46:b1:06:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: kube-ipvs0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 1a:0d:f4:cf:ab:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.1/32 brd 10.10.0.1 scope global kube-ipvs0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.0.200/32 brd 10.10.0.200 scope global kube-ipvs0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.189.192/32 brd 10.10.189.192 scope global kube-ipvs0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 192.168.102.128/32 brd 192.168.102.128 scope global tunl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: cali44ab0f7df0f@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: what pod cidr range you gave when setting up the cluster?

Comment: The pod cidr range i set up is:192.168.0.0/16.  the service cidr range i set up is: 10.10.0.0/16

Comment: Is IP forwarding enabled? you can check it using `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

Comment: Additionally: are your VMs hosted in cloud? If yes, did you create a firewall rule to allow traffic between containers on different hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route table doesn't have route for tunl0 interface. You can include the environement IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD on calico.yaml file under the calico-node section.

```
Example:
 containers:
 - name: calico-node
   image: xxxxxxx
   env:
    - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
      value: interface=ens192
```

Comment: hi,Manickam, I  included the environement IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD on calico.yaml, And reapply the yaml. but I still access the pod on the other pod.